# How do i open files in python with variable as part of filename?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

something where the filenames have numbers 1-32 and i want to open them in order in a loop like:

```
i = 1
while i < 32:
filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file[i].txt"
f = open(filename, 'r')
text = f.read()
f.close()
```

but this looks for the file "file[i].txt" instead of file1.txt, file2.txt and so on. how do i make the variable become a variable inside double quotes? and yes i know its not indented, please dont think i m that stupid.

I think this might work :
Build the filename just like you'd build any other string that contains a variable:

```
filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file" + str( i ) + ".txt"
```

or if you need more options for formatting the number:

```
filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file%d.txt" % i
```

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change your loop to `while i <= 32` or you'll exclude the file with 32 in it's name.
Your second option `filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file%d.txt" % i` should work.

If the numbers in your files are 0 padded, like 'file01.txt', 'file02.txt', you can use `%.2d` instead of plain old %d

Comment: If files are 0 padded then we can also do as filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file0%d.txt" % i. I think this should also work.

Comment: Don't do that. That would assume that there's a 0 before every number from 1 to 32. %.2d will add 0's if there's only one number. For every number from 10-32, it'll leave the numbers as they are.

Comment: If files are have four integers in the end then we can also do as filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file%.4d.txt" % i. I think this should also work. Like filename is file1234.

Answer (score 5):

You've already provided an answer. Btw, use `with` context manager instead of manually calling `close()`:

```
i = 1
while i < 32:
    filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file%d.txt" % i
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the options you gave would work, why not just test it out?

```
filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file" + str( i ) + ".txt"
```

or

```
filename = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\file%d.txt" % i
```